# tsun in inferior term prompts each character of input

Tags: repl

I came across a problem when I run tsun in an inferior ansi-term (or term, eshell) buffer of emacs(24.4.1) in Debian 8.5. The tsun REPL echos every character while I input as shown in the following picture.

[image]

Meanwhile, the similar issues occur with comint-run, ts-node, etc.
How should I fix such a mess?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like option **`echo-keystrokes`** might be the culprit.

Try setting it to zero (`0`): `M-x customize-option echo-keystrokes`.

If it does not stay off then look for some code that you are using that is the culprit: check your init file, recursively bisecting it to find the part that turns it back on.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  But changing echo-keystrokes from original 0.02 to 0(must be number by the doc) doesn't help. i use spacemacs. But the situation is the same when i switch to general emacs with my own configurations or neat emacs without any .emacs and .emacs.d  and change the values of echo-keystrokes from original 1  to 0.  It seems that it's not caused by this option. Node REPL works except the backspace causes messy echoes. swi-prolog works very well as inferior process.

Comment: My bad; I should have said *zero* instead of *nil*. I've corrected that now. But apparently the cause is elsewhere, not `echo-keystrokes`.

Answer (score 0):

This is `ansi-term` not handling the `CHA` escape sequence for absolute column positioning.  I've handed in a patch to fix this, it should be part of Emacs 26, but you can use it now by either building Emacs from Git or patching `term-handle-ansi-escape` by adding the following clause to the huge `cond`:

```
;; \E[G - cursor motion to absolute column (terminfo: hpa)
((eq char ?G)
 (term-move-columns (- (max 0 (min term-width term-terminal-parameter))
                       (term-current-column))))
```